# Redirect to other address Wordpress MAMP

Tags: wordpress, mamp

I move my wordpress from my server to my localhost in the database I change

> http://www.hybrid-tech.net/praxi3 to `http:// localhost:8888/praxi3`

after that, when I try to see the website on my localhost I go to

> `http:// localhost:8888/praxi3`

but it's redirect me to

> `http:// localhost/praxi3`

and I'm don't understand why. I back up a restore many times this database and I still getting this problem.

Thanks in advance for your help.

PD: I'm using mamp. The localhost link are without the space I mean `http://lo....`

Answer (score 0):

You should check your mamp configs : 
 Is your apache port set to 80 ? If so the server redirects you to the 80 (default web port)
 Try setting it to the 8888 port and refresh your page using the flush cache command :

```
ctrl+r or apple+r
```